# JavaScript - Move entire UL > LI list as fragment into a DIV

Tags: javascript

With the `Move_ULLI` function, how is it possible to move the entire List (UL+LI) into the DIV with the `destination` class?

I'm not intending to use IDs to identify DIVs or UL List, just by ClassName() and TagName().

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="destination"></div>

  <input type="button" onclick="Move_ULLI" value="MOVE ULLI" />

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>

  function Move_ULLI() {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment.appendChild(document.querySelectorAll("ul"));
    document.getElementsByClassName('destination').appendChild(fragment);
  }
  
</script>
```

**Intended Result:**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="destination">
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <input type="button" onclick="Move_ULLI" value="MOVE ULLI" />

</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues:

- You never call the function. The `onclick` attribute lacks the parentheses after the function to actually invoke it.
- `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list and has no `appendChild` method. Use `querySelector` instead (with the right selector)
- `querySelectorAll` returns a node list, while you want to just get a node, so use `querySelector` there as well
- There is no need to create a fragment. Just append the `ul` node and it will move.

```js
function Move_ULLI() {
  document.querySelector('.destination')
          .appendChild(document.querySelector("ul"));
}
```

```css
.destination { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="destination"></div>

  <input type="button" onclick="Move_ULLI()" value="MOVE ULLI" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things wrong with your example:

1. You need to add the parenthesis to the end of your function name in your inline `onclick` markup for your Html (I would suggest moving to using event listeners, but for the sake of giving you a working example I am leaving it).
2. If you use `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` you get back a node list, so you either have to index the node list or use `querySelector` and/or `getElememtById`

Here's a working solution:

```js
function Move_ULLI() {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment.appendChild(document.querySelector("ul"));
    document.getElementsByClassName('destination')[0].appendChild(fragment);
}
```

```css
.destination {
   background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="destination"></div>
  <button type="button" onclick="Move_ULLI();">
  MOVE ULLI
  </button>
</div>
```

**Solution using event handler**

```js
function Move_ULLI() {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment.appendChild(document.querySelector("ul"));
    document.getElementsByClassName('destination')[0].appendChild(fragment);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", Move_ULLI);
});
```

```css
.destination {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="destination"></div>
      <button type="button" onclick="Move_ULLI();">
      MOVE ULLI
      </button>
    </div>
```